# Dynamic editable rows on a ASP.Net MVC2 page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have to build a page which contains some text boxes and a grid layout. There is an add button next to the grid, clicking on which should results to creating a blank row in the grid where user can fill the required data. User can continue adding data to the grid as per the wish and finally click the submit button on the form. This submit should post the entire data(data from the text boxes and grid) to the server. I am using MVC2 with VS2008.

Please let me know how should I proceed to achieve this in MVC ways. As it involves lots of client side handling i.e. building the grid item collection and validations I want to know which approach I should take.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935756/what-is-the-most-user-friendly-asp-net-mvc-grid-view-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with KnockoutJs grid editor.This perfectly suited my requirement. http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html